# Is it possible to access .NET APIs with JRuby?

Tags: .net, ruby, jruby

I know that JRuby can access COM APIs, but can it interface with .NET?

Comment: I think if you want to access .NET via Ruby, the easiest way is to go with IronRuby: http://ironruby.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use [Mainsoft for Java EE](http://dev.mainsoft.com/Default.aspx?tabid=166) alias Grasshopper. This [article](http://reddevnews.com/articles/2008/06/01/visual-studio-and-java.aspx) gives a wide level overview. It appears to be free to develop in and run.